# CSS Selector issue with RVEST

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to select products from Wine.com using Rvest

```
library(rvest)
wine <- read_html("http://www.wine.com/v6/90-Rated-Under-20/wine/list.aspx?N=7155+2407")

p <-wine %>%
  html_nodes(".listProductName") %>%
  html_text()
```

I've used CSS Selector to see that .listProductName selects the product node.  When I run this code nothing is returned.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem lies in the fact the nodes you are searching for resides inside a `aspx form`, so they are generated only for a browser, not for curl request.
I see two solution to this:

---

### Using rvest

If you are only interested in the product name or something simple you can use:

```
p <-wine %>%
  html_nodes('.prodItemInfo_link') %>%
  html_text()
```

I got that selector analysing the result of `wine %>% html_nodes('a')` looking for a wine name, and found that the products where inside that class.

---

### Using RSelenium

Provided that you have Selenium installed and running we can simulate a normal browser request:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                      , port = 4444L
                      , browserName = "htmlunit"
)
remDr$open()
url <- "http://www.wine.com/v6/90-Rated-Under-20/wine/list.aspx?N=7155+2407"
remDr$navigate(url)
```

This page should be identical to what we see using a normal browser so we can select the nodes with their class:

```
webElems <- remDr$findElements(using = 'class', 'listProductName')
```

and then extract the text content for each node:

```
wines <- sapply(webElems, function(x) x$getElementText())
```

---

Hope this helps